# Одновременный touch двух элементов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста логику данной цепочки.
Имеется три кнопки, каждая из них делает вызов функции:

```
var targets = []; // Создадим пустой массив
buttons.find("canvas").on('touchstart',
    function(e) {
        targets = []; // Очистим массив
        targets.push(e.target); // Добавим значение в массив
    }
)
buttons.find("canvas").on('touchend',
    function(e) {
        queryEvent(targets[0]); // Вызовем функцию с параметром первого значения массива
        targets = []; // Очистим массив
    }
)
```

Проблема в том что если зажать две крайние (1 и 3) кнопки, то вызовется кнопка с номером 2, в остальном проблем нету. Что не так ?!?

> Обратите внимание, здесь метод `touch`, то есть это сенсорный экран (можно зажать две кнопки сразу).

Просьба ссылки на ресурсы не давать, интересует только ваше решение.

Comment: тут проблема не в событиях, а в алгоритме. то, что у вас написано реализует какой-то сюр. напишите что вы хотите получить в итоге. и кстати зачем закрыли предыдущий вопрос, там был шанс довести обсуждение до логического завершения.

Comment: Так некому было это делать, по этому решил открыть новый. Проблема в том что при двух касаниях метод `touchstart` или `end` записывает два значения, и естественно их исполняет. Так вот я думаю как бы так сделать что бы эти значения записывались в массив и исполнялось только одно без разницы какое. Хотя вообще проблема решилась заменой `touchstart` на `click` и двойного срабатывания больше нет, но все же хочу узнать как решить такую проблему методом `touch`

   Такой метод который мне предложили в прошлом вопросе всегда выдает ошибку о том что не существует такого объекта. Делал все по примера

Comment: Неча вопрос заново делать.

> Просьба ссылки на ресурсы не давать, интересует только ваше решение.

это не приветсвуется правилами

> Так некому было это делать

вам на фриланс с такими идеями.

Comment: А вам то что от того открыл я его дважды, хоть трижды, это мое дело, я бы понял такую реакцию, если же это был ваш ресурс и вам не хотелось бы забивать БД не нужной инфой, или же вам платят за модерацию ? 

Вы говорите это не фриланс с такими идеями, опять же скажу, если вам не интересно не читайте этот вопрос, читайте другие, форум по вашему вообще для чего нужен. Не надо закрывать мои вопросы, я сам решу надо мне его закрывать или не надо, не ваше дело.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, изначально ошибка у вас в том, что вы используете jquery, которая touch-events из коробки не поддерживает (хотя и перехватывает), поэтому и "объект не найден". Вам надо либо использовать какие-то другие библиотеки (jquery mobile, zepto и т.д. - там события другие и обработка будет другой), либо писать на чистом javascript'е в стиле:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
  // вот тут e.changedTouches и прочие будут доступны
},false);
```

Во-вторых, вы так и не сказали что у вас за обработка такая идет, что вам не важно что обрабатывать. Ну ладно, первый тач обработать можно, но что делать если первый тач отжали и нажали снова, не отжимая остальные, он должен быть снова как бы первым и что делать если отожмут предыдущий нажатый тач (сумбур моего объяснения - отсутствие какой-либо постановки задачи с вашей стороны). например:

1. нажали указательным, средним, большим.
2. отжали указательный - сработало ваше событие queryEvent
3. нажали указательным
4. отжали средний - должно сработать событие или нет?

В третьих, оно же в нулевых http://sscce.org/

Comment: Спасибо ! Единственный вменяемый ответ. Да, с чистым бы JS проблем не было бы, хотелось исключительно на jQuery. Тут моя ошибка, надо было сразу использовать jQuery Mobile. А про отжатие пальцев, то я думаю должно срабатывать то события которое мы отжали (touchend), если же отжали все сразу, то из массива трех событий можно брать любое наугад. Думаю вопрос закрыт !